# Display raster value as a tooltip

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, tooltip

I would like to display the value of a raster (at least one band) as a tooltip next to the mouse in Qgis.

The process would be :

1. I select the raster layer
2. when I move the cursor over the map (or maybe each time I click with the mouse),I can see the value next to the cursor.

I know the plugin ValueTool which is very useful for debug purposes but not so easy to use in order to analyse the data. It is often difficult to point at the right place with the mouse and at the same time to read the value in the plugin.

Comment: To enable your desired behavior with Value Tool plugin you need to select 'Options' tab at plugin and mark its 'Enable' box.

Comment: Did you give my answer a try?

Comment: @Germán Carrillo I tried it out. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way of doing it is creating your own Map Tool and setting a QTimer (as QGIS does for MapTips) on mouse move events to show the tooltip. The following code illustrates it (works if you run it in the QGIS Python Console).

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRaster
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolTip

class TooltipRasterMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.timerMapTips = QTimer( self.canvas )
        self.timerMapTips.timeout.connect( self.showMapTip )

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        pass

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        pass

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.canvas.underMouse(): # Only if mouse is over the map
            QToolTip.hideText()
            self.timerMapTips.start( 700 ) # time in milliseconds

    def deactivate(self):
        self.timerMapTips.stop()

    def showMapTip( self ):
        self.timerMapTips.stop()
        if self.canvas.underMouse():
            rLayer = iface.activeLayer()
            if type(rLayer) is QgsRasterLayer:
                ident = rLayer.dataProvider().identify( self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY()), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue )
                if ident.isValid():
                    text = ", ".join(['{0:g}'.format(r) for r in ident.results().values() if r is not None] )
                else:
                    text = "Non valid value"
                QToolTip.showText( self.canvas.mapToGlobal( self.canvas.mouseLastXY() ), text, self.canvas )


tooltipRaster = TooltipRasterMapTool( iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( tooltipRaster ) # Use your Map Tool!
```

### Test plugin

Since a plugin would be much more convenient, I've created this basic [test plugin](https://github.com/gacarrillor/test/tree/tooltip_raster_values) ready to use, there you find installation instructions as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is exactly what I need. Best regards. JB

Answer (score 3):

This is a workaround using a MapTips on vector layer:

1. Create a Vector layer (points/grids) from your Raster layer.
2. Make the Vector layer transparent.
3. Build Map Tips on the Vector layer

In detail:

(1) Start `Processing Toolbox | SAGA | Vector <-> raster | Raster values to points`

- Assign your Raster layer to the `Grids`
- Set Type to `[1] cells` which creates gridded vector cell at each raster cell
- [Run] this tool which returns a *Shapes* vector layer . Its attribute table has *ID*, *X*, *Y* and *RasterValue* (named after your Raster layer).

(2) Open `Layer Properties` of this *Shapes* layer. Open `Style` tab and set Transparency to 100%, so that this *Shapes* layer becomes invisible.

(3) Go to  `Display` tab and select *RasterValue* field to `Field` drop-down menu. [OK] to close the window.

(4) Click on the `Map Tips` icon of the Attributes toolbar to activate it.

Answer (score 3):

To enable your desired behavior with **Value Tool** plugin you need to select 'Options' tab at plugin and mark its 'Enable' box.

[image]

Afterward (change newly to 'Table' tab), when you click at the right place with the mouse, values and coordinates will remain static until next mouse click. I hope that it helps.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

To print results (**pyperclip** python module can be used to print to clipboard), I slightly adapted code in excellent Germán Carrillo's answer to do that.

```
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer, QgsRaster
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QToolTip

class TooltipRasterMapTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        QgsMapToolEmitPoint.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        self.timerMapTips = QTimer( self.canvas )
        self.timerMapTips.timeout.connect( self.showMapTip )

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        point = self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY())
        print '({:.4f}, {:.4f})'.format(point[0], point[1])
        rLayer = iface.activeLayer()
        if type(rLayer) is QgsRasterLayer:
            ident = rLayer.dataProvider().identify( point, QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue )
            if ident.isValid():
                text = ", ".join(['{0:g}'.format(r) for r in ident.results().values() if r is not None] )
            else:
                text = "Non valid value"

        print text


    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        pass

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if self.canvas.underMouse(): # Only if mouse is over the map
            QToolTip.hideText()
            self.timerMapTips.start( 700 ) # time in milliseconds

    def deactivate(self):
        self.timerMapTips.stop()

    def showMapTip( self ):
        self.timerMapTips.stop()
        if self.canvas.underMouse():
            rLayer = iface.activeLayer()
            if type(rLayer) is QgsRasterLayer:
                ident = rLayer.dataProvider().identify( self.toMapCoordinates(self.canvas.mouseLastXY()), QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue )
                if ident.isValid():
                    text = ", ".join(['{0:g}'.format(r) for r in ident.results().values() if r is not None] )
                else:
                    text = "Non valid value"
                QToolTip.showText( self.canvas.mapToGlobal( self.canvas.mouseLastXY() ), text, self.canvas )


tooltipRaster = TooltipRasterMapTool( iface.mapCanvas() )
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( tooltipRaster ) # Use your Map Tool!
```

I tried it out with a RGB tif raster; as it can be observed at next image:

[image]