# Importing classification bitmap made by another software into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, classification

I am currently trying to import a classification bitmap made by our own deep learning software into QGIS. The classification is saved in a TIF file, the classes are 8-bit integers. We have the class names in a text file and the coordinates (MTM) to geo-reference the image in another text file.

Ideally, we would want QGIS to assign colours to the classes, and when the user clicks on a particular pixel of the image, to have QGIS display the class name.

Comment: Perhaps test plugin provided in this question, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245280/display-raster-value-as-a-tooltip, it can help.

Comment: if you put the coordinates in "world file" format then QGIS will load the TIFF and use the world file data to put the data in the right place - you might have to specify the coordinate system manually (its not part of the world file spec). The world file for FOO.TIFF is FOO.TFW - search for more.

Comment: Thanks a lot about the TFW file info! That did the job. The image is now geo-referenced. I am testing the plugin now.

Comment: Many thanks also for the plugin! I modified it to read the class description file at initialization and it displays the class number along with its name when I move the cursor over the classification bitmap. Wonderful! Thanks again!